# how to unstash a specific file that was untracked

Tags: git

I stashed a bunch of files, including some non tracked ones. (`git stash -u`)

I know how to get a file back normally (`git checkout stash@{0} -- file`). But this does not work for untracked files

`git stash show stash@{0} -u` shows that the file is there. But checkout doesnt accept the request - says there is no such file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The untracked files are not in the head of the stash entry `stash@{0}`. Take a look at this example.

```
git init foo
cd foo
touch a.txt
git add a.txt
git commit -ma
touch b.txt
git stash -u
```

Run `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --name-only stash@{0}`. We can see a graph like this

```
*-.   28623e0 (refs/stash) WIP on master: 1aa6ae7 www
|\ \
| | * 955939f untracked files on master: 1aa6ae7 www
| |   b.txt
| * f2bc3ae index on master: 1aa6ae7 www
|/
* 1aa6ae7 (HEAD -> master) www
  a.txt
```

`b.txt` is committed in `955939f`, the 3rd parent of the stash head.

```
git checkout stash@{0}^3 -- b.txt
```

Comment: or `git checkout 955939f -- file`. I could not make the ^3 thing work, I think my shell was interpreting it and I couldnt work out how to escape it. Anyway TY - that worked. I dont know why people complain about git being complicated its really very simple /s

Comment: @pm100 If your shell is `cmd`, try `git checkout stash@{0}^^3 -- b.txt`. BTW, in `powershell`, try `git checkout stash@\`{0\`}^3 -- b.txt`.

Comment: I already switched to CMD to get the {} working ! I could not be bothered to find out cmds quirks. Obv that git not written by windows user

Comment: @pm100 Linus Torvalds is not a big fan of Windows. On Windows, `git bash` is recommended.